# Detox with Mirage.js [Mock API Call] React-Native

Tags: react-native, detox, miragejs

I'm working on some tests using Detox for my React-Native application, one of those test is a flow where I need to check that the user's session is secured. If not, I'm sending an SMS Verification Code.

Test : Success to mock the `POST` API Call `api/sessions/:sessionId, {code : 123456}`

Problem : Mirage is not catching the call, so of course my Saga return an error for the fake code `123456`, where I want instead Mirage.JS to return `true` to continue the flow.

Here are the file  (`file.spec.js`):

```
import { Server } from "miragejs"
import { makeServer } from "./server";
let server; 

beforeEach(() => {
    server = makeServer({ environment: "development" });
})

afterEach(() => {
    server.shutdown()
})

describe('SecureFlow',  () => {
    it("should do nav to a project and start Investment Flow", async () => {
        server.get("https://random-api.eu/sessions/:sessionId", () => {
            return new Response( 200, {}, { ok: true });
          });
        await basicNavigation(); //randomNavigation until the secure part (Screen)
        await element(by.id('Accept-andLend')).tap();
        await element(by.id('textInput-SMSCode')).typeText("123456"); 
    })
})
```

`server.js`

```
import { Server, Model, Factory } from "miragejs";

export function makeServer({ environment = "development" } = {}) {
  let server = new Server({
    environment,
    models: {

    },
    routes() {
      this.post("https://random-api.eu/sessions/:sessionId", schema => {
        return [{ok: true}];
      });
    }
  });

  return server;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that Mirage is running at all? Does it show any messages in the console, or can you put a console.log() in your routes() hook and make sure that code is running?